# Need extra line with <br> after heading to hold line spacing for following text in r markdown

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown, knitr

I'm trying to knit a R Markdown document to a Word output using a reference document. After the title, the line spacing for any paragraph text is what it should be at 1.15. However, if I add a heading after some paragraph text, if I don't add a line break or 
 after the heading, the following paragraph text holds the font of the reference doc, but the line spacing defaults to 1.0.

The line break results in extra spacing below the heading that is not wanted.

Below are the YAML headers

```
---
title: "something: `r params$program`"
output:
    officedown::rdocx_document: 
        reference_docx: P:/Reference_doc
params:
  program: "something"
---
```

And here is some example code to illustrate:

```
## No line break heading

<p>Here is some text that has a line spacing of 1.0, which does not match the reference documents line spacing of 1.15. The actual font and font size is correct, but not the line spacing. This occurs because there is no <br> below the heading.<p> 

## Line break heading

<br>
<p>Here is some text that has the proper line spacing of 1.15, which does match the reference document line spacing. The line spacing is correct here, but requires the line break above, which leads to a large space between the heading and the paragraph.<p>
```

And this is what the output looks like

[Word output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyOYW.png)

Anyone know how I keep keep the line spacing but remove the line break. Is there some workaround like changing the font size of the line break?

Comment: In Word jargon there is a huge difference between a header and a heading. If you mean heading, as I suspect, please edit your question to show that. http://addbalance.com/word/headersheadings.htm --- You would want to use a paragraph break and change the line spacing of the heading and/or the following paragraph, preferably in the style.